# Checking for Duplicates before SQLite database update

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, jquery-mobile

I have here a working function that updates the database, but i want to put a trapping where it would not accept duplicate names. I have read about using NOT EXISTS statement but it does not return where it is true or not.

Here is my code:

```
function editDB( eName ) {

    var clubDetect = $('#clubDisplay').text();

    if ( -- condition that checks if the Name exists in the database goes here -- )
        db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql('UPDATE SoccerPlayer SET Name = ? WHERE Club=?',[ eName, clubDetect ]); });        

    else
        alert("existing name");

}
```

I am stuck with this problem, any help will be gladly accepted. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition in your WHERE clause that prevents the UPDATE when the name already exists. Then you can you can check [rowsAffected](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#database-query-results) in your callback to see if the UPDATE took or not.

Something like this:

```
function editDB( eName ) {

    var callback = function(tx, results){
        if (!results.rowsAffected) {
            alert("existing name");
        }
    };

    var sql = "UPDATE SoccerPlayer SET Name = ? WHERE Club=? AND ? NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM SoccerPlayer)";
    db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(sql,[ eName, clubDetect, eName ], callback); });        
}
```

Comment: Thanks it prevents duplicate now, but it doesn't trigger the callback at all.